# Print two sheets in the same page of PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the code below to export two tables set across two sheets to a PDF. The print areas of both tables are pre-marked in the sheets so the export comes out good. However, the first table is printed to page 1 and the second table to page 2 in the PDF. This sometimes leaves a lot of blank space in e.g. the first page because table 1 is only a few rows.

Is it possible in vba to start the second table (located in the second sheet) from where the print area of the first table/sheet ends in the PDF's first page?
I can't have both tables in the same sheet.

```
Dim fname As String, fpath As String, srcFile As String
fpath = "C:\"
fname = "export.pdf"
srcFile = ThisWorkbook.Name
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(Sheet1.Name, Sheet2.Name)).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fpath & fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

This way of saving must be handled in Excel `PageSetup` settings, but it does offer this possibility **only per sheet**. So, you should use a trick, copying both tables in discussion an a temporary worksheet, set `PageSetup.FitToPagesTall` and `FitToPagesWide` to 1, publish the newly created sheet and delete it at the end:

```
Sub exportTwoSheetsInOne()
 Dim fname As String, fpath As String, wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
 Dim tblSh1 As ListObject, tblSh2 As ListObject, lastR As Long

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 fpath = wb.Path & "\":  fname = "export.pdf" 'you can use a different path if user permissions permit that location

 Set tblSh1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1)
 Set tblSh2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects(1)

 Set sh = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.count))
 tblSh1.Range.Copy sh.Range("A1")

 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'calculate the place where the second table to be copied
 tblSh2.Range.Copy sh.Range("A" & lastR + 2)
 
If Dir(fpath & fname) <> "" Then Kill fpath & fname

Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'some optimization
    With sh
       With .PageSetup
           .FitToPagesTall = 1
           .FitToPagesWide = 1
       End With
       .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=fpath & fname, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: @dsauce Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If you tested it, doesn't it provide the result you need?

Comment: Hi, sorry, haven't been able to yet but i will be able to later today. I might have to use some more tricks because both contents are very different to be put into the same sheet.

Comment: @dsauce Theoretically, if you paste the second one at a row distance of the first one ending, and the sheet `PageSetup` shrinks the page to accept all in one page, Excel takes care of the differences i discussion, I think.